A metric induced on a surface of revolution is isometric to a warped product metric
I am trying to prove that A metric induced on a surface of revolution is  isometric to a warped product metric
Definitions:

A surface of revolution is generated by rotating a curve $C$ in the half-plane $H = \{(r, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid r > 0\}$ around the $z$-axis. In this case, the surface $S_C \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is given by the set:

$$
S_C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \in C\}.
$$
A smooth local parametrization $\gamma(t) = (a(t), b(t))$ of the curve $C$ can be used to parametrize the surface of revolution by:
$$
X(t, \theta) = (a(t) \sin \theta, a(t) \cos \theta, b(t)),
$$
where $t$ and $\theta$ are the parameters. The induced metric on $S_C$ is then given in terms of this parametrization.

Warped Products:
A warped product is a type of Riemannian manifold constructed from two Riemannian manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ with a smooth positive function $f: M_1 \to (0, \infty)$. The warped product metric on $M_1 \times_f M_2$ is defined as:

$$
g_{(p_1, p_2)}((v_1, v_2), (w_1, w_2)) = g_1|_{p_1}(v_1, w_1) + f(p_1)^2 g_2|_{p_2}(v_2, w_2),
$$
where $v_1, w_1 \in T_{p_1} M_1$ and $v_2, w_2 \in T_{p_2} M_2$.
The problem:
Let $C \subset H = \{(r, z) \mid r > 0\}$ be a smooth 1-dimensional embedded submanifold, and let $S_C \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the surface of revolution generated by rotating $C$ about the $z$-axis.
Consider the parametrization of the surface $S_C$:
$$
X(t, \theta) = (a(t) \sin \theta, a(t) \cos \theta, b(t)),
$$
where:

$t$ parametrizes the curve $C$,
$\theta$ is the angular parameter for the rotation around the $z$-axis.

The induced metric on the surface of revolution is:
$$
g = (a'(t)^2 + b'(t)^2) \, dt^2 + a(t)^2 \, d\theta^2.
$$
which I can compoare with the Warped Product Metric
$$
g = g_1(t) + f(t)^2 g_2(\theta),
$$
where $g_1(t)$ is the metric on the curve $C$, $f(t)$ is a smooth function representing the "warping factor," and $g_2(\theta)$ is the standard metric on $S^1$.
In our case, the curve $C$ is parametrized by $(a(t), b(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the metric on $C$ is simply the Euclidean metric:
$$
g_1 = a'(t)^2 + b'(t)^2.
$$
The warping function $f(t)$ is the distance to the $z$-axis, which is given by $a(t)$. Finally, the metric on $S^1$ is $d\theta^2$.
Thus, the warped product metric is:
$$
g = (a'(t)^2 + b'(t)^2) \, dt^2 + a(t)^2 \, d\theta^2,
$$
Is this approach correct? The problem is that I think I have to exhibit an isometry, which I have not done. What would the isometry be and how do you find it?

I think you mean that $S_C$ is defined as
$$ S_C:=\{(x,y,z) \colon \left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z\right)\in C  \}.$$
The isometry that you are looking for is
$$C\times \mathbb S^1 \to S_C, \qquad \left((y,z), e^{i\theta}\right)\mapsto (y \sin(\theta), y\cos(\theta), z).$$
Clearly, as you already observed, this is an isometry if you fix on the product the warped product metric by the projection map  $f\colon C\to (0,+\infty)$ sending $(y,z)$ to $y$.

I am having trouble proving that that is an isometry, call it $\phi$ I have to verify the definition $g_p(v,w)=\tilde g_{\phi(p)}(d\phi_p(v), d\phi_p(w))$, with $\tilde g$ the metric on $S_c$. Not very sure how to compute $ d\phi_p$, would p be $(y,z, e^{-i\theta})$ ?
